# cannot change font to Helvetica in Matplotlib in Python on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to change the matplotlib font to helvetica, which I'd like to use in a PDF plot.  I try the following:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('PDF')
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib import rc
plt.rcParams['ps.useafm'] = True
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
plt.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
```

This does not work -- when I run my code with --verbose-debug, I get the error:

```
backend WXAgg version 2.8.10.1
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:833: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
findfont: Could not match :family=sans-serif:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=medium. Returning /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Vera.ttf
Assigning font /F1 = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Vera.ttf
Embedding font /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Vera.ttf
Writing TrueType font
```

So apparently it cannot find Helvetica.  I am not sure why.  I have Helvetica in the afm directory of mpl-data, and when matplotlib initiates it reads it and outputs:

```
createFontDict: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/afm/Helvetica.afm
```

Do I need a special .ttf Helvetica font in addition?  If so, how can I get it?  I know I have Helvetica on my system since I see it in Illustrator and many other programs.

I am using Enthought Python distribution as follows:

```
$ python
Enthought Python Distribution -- http://www.enthought.com
Version: 6.2-2 (32-bit)

Python 2.6.5 |EPD 6.2-2 (32-bit)| (r265:79063, May 28 2010, 15:13:03) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5488)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'0.99.3'
```

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is to use fondu to convert the .dfont Helvetica font from Mac OS X into .ttf, and then place that in the mpl-data/fonts directory that Matplotlib looks in.  That solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question and answering it — I'm sure this will come in helpful to me sometime, and this is exactly the sort of thing StackOverflow was created for.

Comment: Could you provide with more details? The step-by-step solution by Max Malysh works like a charm!

Answer (score 20):

Step-by-step solution for OS X 10.11 El Capitan and Python 3 (based on [this post](http://blog.olgabotvinnik.com/blog/2012/11/15/2012-11-15-how-to-set-helvetica-as-the-default-sans-serif-font-in/)).

1. Install fondu:
   `brew install fondu`
2. Find out matplotlib location:

   ```
   python3 -c "import matplotlib ; print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())"
   ```

   For me it's `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc`
3. Make a copy of Helvetica:

   ```
   mkdir ~/Desktop/font_copies
   cp /System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.dfont ~/Desktop/font_copies
   ```
4. Convert the Helvetica copy we've made from `dfont` to `ttf`:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/
   fondu -show ~/Desktop/font_copies/Helvetica.dfont
   ```
5. Remove font cache: `rm ~/.matplotlib/fontList.py3k.cache`

Done! Now you can use Helvetica:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('font', family='Helvetica')
```

Comment: This step-by-step solution works perfectly and should be up-voted!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: You may also need remove: ``~/.matplotlib/fontList.json`` and ``~/.matplotlib/fontList.cache``.

Comment: On my Catalina machine the file is `Helvetica.ttc`, not `Helvetica.dfont`. I couldn't figure out how to use `fondu` for this, but there are online services which perform TTC -> TTF conversion which worked. As @LibinWen says you may also need to remove other font cache files.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, I wrote a script that *automatically adds `.ttf` fonts from a custom folder* to `mpl-data`. Place your `.ttf` files in some folder, and run this script to move them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Imports
import os
import re
import shutil
from glob import glob
from matplotlib import matplotlib_fname
from matplotlib import get_cachedir

# Copy files over
_dir_data = re.sub('/matplotlibrc$', '', matplotlib_fname())
dir_source = '<your-font-directory-here>'
dir_dest = f'{_dir_data}/fonts/ttf'
# print(f'Transfering .ttf and .otf files from {dir_source} to {dir_dest}.')
for file in glob(f'{dir_source}/*.[ot]tf'):
    if not os.path.exists(f'{dir_dest}/{os.path.basename(file)}'):
        print(f'Adding font "{os.path.basename(file)}".')
        shutil.copy(file, dir_dest)

# Delete cache
dir_cache = get_cachedir()
for file in glob(f'{dir_cache}/*.cache') + glob(f'{dir_cache}/font*'):
    if not os.path.isdir(file): # don't dump the tex.cache folder... because dunno why
        os.remove(file)
        print(f'Deleted font cache {file}.')
```

---

This originally appeared in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47743010/4970632).