# Can I distribute just one extra font file with a matplotlib application?

Tags: matplotlib

I’m writing a Python program that uses matplotlib. I’d like to use a font that isn’t included with matplotlib. (Well, I want to use Lucida Grande, which is included in OS X, but [matplotlib can’t read the .dfont file directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176350/cannot-change-font-to-helvetica-in-matplotlib-in-python-on-mac-os-x-10-6) so I need to distribute my own .ttf font.)

It seems like matplotlib only ever looks in one directory for fonts: `mpl-data/fonts`. It’s possible to [tweak matplotlib’s configuration](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) to change where the `mpl-data` directory is, but it doesn’t seem to be possible to specify *more than one* such directory in which fonts may be found. Is that accurate?

(It would be possible for me to put the font in my system’s global `mpl-data` directory, but it feels wrong for an application to muck around with a globally-used directory like that. And I sure as hell don’t want to include the entire `mpl-data`-plus-one-file with my application.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to expand on the response provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14171680/2942522) which uses the matplotlib [font manager module](http://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html). Specifically, it looks like you can specify the absolute path to your font with the `fname` argument to `matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties` (see the docs here: http://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties)

Modifying the previous SO response (to a slightly simpler question) below, this is certainly worth a try if you can specify the absolute path to the ttf font file in your workflow. I've used a built-in MacOS font below (and that works), but maybe try substituting your particular absolute path & font to see if it works.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use( "agg" ) #some backend sensitivity explained in previous SO response
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#specify the absolute path to your font file:
absolute_path_to_ttf_file = '/opt/X11/share/fonts/TTF/VeraSe.ttf'
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=absolute_path_to_ttf_file)    
ax.set_title('Text in a cool font', fontproperties=prop, size=40)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: If I include the font within my application, I can get its absolute path using `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'some_directory/my_font.ttf')`. Thanks!